# Non-tame 3-manifolds covered by the Euclidean space

Tags: 3-manifolds

An open 3-manifold is *tame* if it is homeomorphic to the interior of a compact manifold. Is there a (known) example of an open 3-manifold that is not tame, has finitely generated fundamental group and universal cover homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I would be interested in an example of an atoroidal, irreducible 3-manifold such that every cover with finitely generated fundamental group is tame, but which does not admit a hyperbolic metric. 

Comment: What does atoroidal mean for a non-tame manifold? I am guessing that the manifold has finitely many tame ends of zero Euler characteristic and any essential torus/Klein bottle comes from one of these ends, is this correct? 

Comment: Yes, if you mean essential immersed torus (it is the same hypothesis as in the geometrization theorem)

Comment: Neat question, Ian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, see the following paper of Freedman and Gabai for lots of examples:

Freedman and Gabai, Covering a nontaming knot by the unlink. Algebr. Geom. Topol. 7 (2007), 1561–1578.

Comment: Thanks! Their paper also answers another question I was wondering about: it gives a 3-manifold with universal cover $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb Z\ast\mathbb Z$ fundamental group that is not hyperbolizable. I was not aware this is possible.

Comment: I meant to say "not hyperbolizable (by the solution of the Tameness Conjecture)".

Comment: Glad to be of service, Igor!

Answer (score 6):

I believe the original such examples (with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$) were due to [Scott and Tucker](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/40/4/481).

Comment: Thank you, Ian! I realized that I referred to [Scott-Tucker] in a preprint last October, but this was for a different example, and I did not look at other parts of the paper. I do not have electonic access, so I get the paper Monday. Incidentally, am I correct that the Tameness Conjecture is open for nonpositively curved 3-manifolds? 

Comment: Freedman was aware of Scott-Tucker, I'm not sure why it's not referenced in their paper (I learned of it in Freedman's seminar). The tameness conjecture is open for non-positively curved 3-manifolds, although the proof I gave works in the pinched negatively curved case, and I think with just a negative upper bound on curvature (I believe this extension appears in notes of Bowditch). 

Comment: Is "negative upper bound on curvature" really enough? I thought, in your paper "hyperbolic cusps" are assumed, while Bowditch gives a proof in the pinched negative case.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure about the case of only an upper bound on curvature, although I suspect the proof should carry through. 

Comment: I know little of dimension 3 but looking at Bowditch's notes I see potential difficulties starting with existence of thick/thin decomposition (Margulis lemma need a lower curvature bound),
and the topology of cusps (which can get ugly). Bowditch also uses some results on convex hulls that depend on a paper of Michael Anderson for which lower curvature bound is needed.